# Proof for Let A, B be nonempty sets and let C, D be sets. If $A \times B \subseteq C \times D$, then $A \subseteq C$ and $B \subseteq D$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Trying to develop a proof for the following statement.  I don't think my proof is quite correct.

Statement: Let A, B be nonempty sets and let C, D be sets.  If $A \times B \subseteq C \times D$, then $A \subseteq C$ and $B \subseteq D$.

Proof:  Let a be any element of A and let b be any element of B.  Then (a,b) $\in A \times B$.  Since $A \times B \subseteq C \times D$, (a, b) $\in C \times D$.  Hence, $a \in C$ and $b \in D$.  Therefore, $A \subseteq C$ and $B \subseteq D$.

Comment: GOOD ONE INDEED

Comment: Your proof is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructor for the class accepted the given proof as valid:

Trying to develop a proof for the following statement. I don't think my proof is quite correct.

Statement: Let A, B be nonempty sets and let C, D be sets. If A×B⊆C×DA×B⊆C×D, then A⊆CA⊆C and B⊆DB⊆D.

Proof: Let a be any element of A and let b be any element of B. Then (a,b) ∈A×B∈A×B. Since A×B⊆C×DA×B⊆C×D, (a, b) ∈C×D∈C×D. Hence, a∈Ca∈C and b∈Db∈D. Therefore, A⊆CA⊆C and B⊆DB⊆D.

Answer (score 2):

Almost, but there is something very subtle going on that makes your proof not quite correct. You need to prove two separate statements: $A \subseteq C$ and $B \subseteq D$. Somewhere you must use the hypothesis that $A$ and $B$ are nonempty; otherwise this is not necessarily true! (For example: $\emptyset \times B \subseteq \emptyset \times \emptyset$ for any set $B$.)

So to prove $A \subseteq C$, we can work like this: Suppose $a \in A$. Then since $B$ is nonempty, there exists some $b \in B$. Now you can use your argument with $(a,b)$ to show that $a \in C$. Similarly you can prove that $B \subseteq D$, this time using that $A$ is nonempty, but this is a different argument (because you must obtain $a$ and $b$ differently).

To hopefully make it clear, when proving that $A \subseteq C$ (i.e. $\forall a. a \in A \Rightarrow a \in C$) you can assume $a \in A$ is given, but you must explain why $b \in B$ exists before you can use it.

Let me put it one more way: Proving $(\forall a. a \in A \Rightarrow a \in C) \wedge (\forall b. b \in B \Rightarrow d \in D)$ is different from proving $\forall a. \forall b. (a \in A \wedge b \in B) \Rightarrow  (a \in C \wedge b \in D)$. You proved the latter, but you were asked to prove the former.

(I can imagine why a lot of people slip up on this one.)

Comment: I don't see it, arkeet.  In the definition of the universe it clearly states that A and B are nonempty sets.  This statement is not part of the hypothesis it is the definition of the universe.  In addition $A \times B$ is defined as $a \in A \land b \in B$.  Since neither A nor B $= \emptyset$  Via direct proof we can assume that $A \times B \subseteq C \times D$.  Remember  $A \times B$ is an ordered pair.  i.e. $A \times B \neq B \times A$.  Therefore, from what I see the proof is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x \in A \land y \in B$

$\implies$ By definition of Cartesian product:
$$(x,y) \in A \times B$$
$\implies$ By hypothesis:
$$(x,y) \in C \times D$$
$\implies$For definition of Cartesian product:
$$x \in C \land y \in D$$
$\implies x \in A \subseteq C \land y\in B \subseteq D $$\blacksquare$